# How to concatenate outputs of multiple aggregate queries dynamically?

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis

I'm building a Postgres query that needs to call an aggregate function on each entry in an array, then concat all of those aggregate values together.

Here's the query for one of the aggregates:

```sql
WITH mvtdata AS
(
  SELECT ST_AsMVTGeom(geom, ST_TileEnvelope(12,513,412)) AS geom, name, description
  FROM feature
  WHERE feature_set = 'river'
    AND ST_Intersects(geom, ST_TileEnvelope(12,513,412))
)
SELECT ST_AsMVT(mvtdata.*, 'river')
FROM mvtdata;
```

I have a separate table that defines the different data layers. Each data layer needs to call the above query and concatenate its results.

Say I have a `layer` table with the following values (I could also use an array if easier):

```
|  name        |
|  'river'     |
|  'building'  |
```

I want to call the above query once for each entry in the table and concatenate the values. Something like:

```sql
WITH riverdata AS
(
  SELECT ST_AsMVTGeom(geom, ST_TileEnvelope(12,513,412)) AS geom, name, description
  FROM feature
  WHERE feature_set = 'river'
    AND ST_Intersects(geom, ST_TileEnvelope(12,513,412))
),
buildingdata AS
(
  SELECT ST_AsMVTGeom(geom, ST_TileEnvelope(12,513,412)) AS geom, name, description
  FROM feature
  WHERE feature_set = 'building'
    AND ST_Intersects(geom, ST_TileEnvelope(12,513,412))
)
SELECT (ST_AsMVT(riverdata.*, 'river') || ST_AsMVT(buildingdata.*, 'building')) mvt
FROM riverdata, buildingdata;
```

How can I write my query to use such a table (or array) to dynamically concatenate an arbitrary number of data layers? It is important to have a separate `ST_AsMVT()` call per layer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply put the key values into a `IN` clasue, so that you can get all desired records a single query. After that, get the records retrieved by the `CTE` and apply the `ST_AsMVT` function.

```
WITH mvtdata AS
(
  SELECT 
    ST_AsMVTGeom(geom, ST_TileEnvelope(12,513,412)) AS geom, 
    name, description,feature_set
  FROM feature
  WHERE feature_set IN ('river','building')
    AND ST_Intersects(geom, ST_TileEnvelope(12,513,412))
)
SELECT 
  ST_AsMVT(mvtdata.*,feature_set)
FROM mvtdata
```

In case you prefer to work with arrays, replace the `IN` with [`ANY/SOME`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-comparisons.html), e.g:

```
WHERE feature_set = ANY ('{river,building}')
```

If it still does not help you, it might be interesting to take a look at `plpgsql`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.concat_mvt(arr_feature TEXT[]) 
RETURNS BYTEA LANGUAGE plpgsql 
AS $BODY$
DECLARE 
  i INTEGER;
  res BYTEA DEFAULT '';
  rec BYTEA;
BEGIN 
FOR i IN 1..array_length(arr_feature,1) LOOP
  WITH mvtdata AS (
  SELECT 
    ST_AsMVTGeom(geom, ST_TileEnvelope(12,513,412)) AS geom, 
    name, description,feature_set
  FROM feature
  WHERE feature_set = arr_feature[i]
    AND ST_Intersects(geom, ST_TileEnvelope(12,513,412))
  ) SELECT ST_AsMVT(mvtdata.*,arr_feature[i])
    FROM mvtdata INTO rec;
  res := res || rec;
END LOOP;
RETURN res;
END $BODY$;
```

.. and call the function like this

```
SELECT concat_mvt('{river,building}')
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but it's not quite what I need. I need multiple `ST_AsMVT()` calls concatenated together using `||`. It is important that each data layer is a separate `ST_AsMVT()` call with its own name, so `'river-building` won't work.

Comment: @TannerSemerad I see. Changing `river-building` to `feature_set` also does not work for you? `WITH mvtdata AS
(
  SELECT ST_AsMVTGeom(geom, ST_TileEnvelope(12,513,412)) AS geom, name, description,feature_set
  FROM feature
  WHERE feature_set IN ('river','building')
    AND ST_Intersects(geom, ST_TileEnvelope(12,513,412))
)
SELECT 
  ST_AsMVT(mvtdata.*,feature_set)
FROM mvtdata`

Comment: @TannerSemerad I'm facing a similar issue with a project of mine and I wonder if you've found a more elegant solution than the function I added two days ago. In case you managed to avoid writing a function I would be very interested :) cheers

Comment: The function worked for me (with a couple problem-specific changes), but your earlier suggestions didn't. The `||` operator was crucial. Thank you so much for posting that function. In regards to a more elegant solution, I saw that `string_agg()` works as an aggregate function that essentially does `||` for each entry. I saw an example here, but haven't yet tried it myself: https://gist.github.com/nyurik/4689ec33d5a8e7713c65c29127c4e968
That particular example looks more complicated than the function I modified from your answer, so in my case the function may be more elegant. Thanks again!

Comment: @TannerSemerad that's good news, I'm glad it could help you after all:) I also looked into pure SQL solutions but they were in my eyes more complicated than anything we could write in PL/pgSQL. Cheers from Germany