# Get separate layers in an mvt

Tags: postgresql, mapbox, postgis, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl

Our platform currently uses pbf tiles(on s3) to render vector layers on Mapbox on the frontend. The pbf tiles have separate layers within them and we use Mapbox layers' source-layer property to style them as separate layers. We are now moving to PostGIS and we want to avoid s3 and directly render the vector tiles as mvt on the frontend.

I am trying to get separate layers from the mvt but the only layer I see is a 'default' layer. I identified this using this [vizualizer tool](https://stevage.github.io/vector-inspector/#?url=&loc=0.02/0/0). I am currently getting the mvt using this query -

```
WITH mvtgeom AS (     
SELECT ST_AsMVTGeom(ST_Transform(ST_Force2D(geom), 3857), 
ST_TileEnvelope(${z}, ${x}, ${y})) 
   AS geom,
   layer, 
   gid
   FROM site-name
   WHERE ST_Intersects(geom, ST_Transform(ST_TileEnvelope(${z}, ${x}, ${y}), 4326)))
SELECT ST_AsMVT(mvtgeom.*) AS mvt FROM mvtgeom;
```

[This](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/314300/st-asmvt-single-layer-with-multiple-ids) issue is very close to my problem but the answer suggests using a UNION, which I want to avoid if possible considering we have to render hundreds of layers.
I also tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60014330/how-to-concatenate-outputs-of-multiple-aggregate-queries-dynamically). In this case, when I put the values of my layer-ids into an IN, I see that those set of layers are rendered as one layer.

(Is there something I need to explore in order to understand how vector tiles are generated so I know how exactly the separate layers are generated? I am new to PostGIS, and I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong or missing something. Any suggestions are appreciated)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Below is the full return signature of `ST_AsMvt`

```
bytea ST_AsMVT(anyelement row, text name, integer extent, text geom_name, text feature_id_name);
```

Later in the [docs](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_AsMVT.html):

> name is the name of the layer. Default is the string "default".

Try using the id (or label, or some other thing specific to each layer) to create a distinct layer name for each layer:

```
WITH mvtgeom AS (     
   SELECT
     ST_AsMVTGeom(ST_Transform(ST_Force2D(geom), 3857) AS geom
     , layer
     , gid
   FROM
     site-name
   WHERE
     ST_Intersects(
       geom,
       ST_Transform(ST_TileEnvelope(${z}, ${x}, ${y}), 4326)
     )
),
tiles as (
   SELECT
     ST_AsMVT(
     mvtgeom.*,
     'layer_' || layer -- this is the layer name argument
   ) AS mvt
   FROM
     mvtgeom
   GROUP BY
     layer
)
-- return single tile composed of layers
SELECT string_agg(mvt, '') from tiles;
```

This `name` property, by the way, is what mapbox uses as the ["source layer"](https://docs.mapbox.com/help/glossary/source-layer/)

Comment: Thank you so much, the `GROUP BY layer` is what was really missing!

Comment: Doesn't this then return multiple rows? For me, to return a single tile with the layers, I then wrap with `select string_agg(mvt,'') as mvt from ( ... )`

Comment: @chrismarx it does return multiple rows, string_agg is the right approach for returning a single row