# how to use `ST_AsMVTGeom` and `ST_AsMVT`

Tags: postgresql, mapbox, postgis

As shown in the below table `grid_cell_data`, I have `geometryOfCellRepresentativeToTreatment` and `geometryOfCellRepresentativeToBuffer` columns, and they contain geometries.

I want to apply both of `ST_AsMVTGeom` and `ST_AsMVT`
as stated in the PostGIS documentation, `ST_AsMVT` takes a geometry column. but when I execute the following code:

```
SELECT ST_AsMVT(grid_cell_data.geometryOfCellRepresentativeToTreatment) 
AS geom
FROM grid_cell_data
```

I get the following error:

```
 pgis_asmvt_transfn: parameter row cannot be other than a rowtype
```

please let me know how to use both of functions `ST_AsMVTGeom` and `ST_AsMVT`

**image**:
[image]

Comment: Can you add the query that raises this exception?

Comment: @JimJones i added it

Comment: You mean this `SELECT ST_AsMVT(g) FROM (
  SELECT geometryOfCellRepresentativeToTreatment AS geom
  FROM grid_cell_data) g`?

Comment: i tested the code you have just sent, i receive the error:parse_column_keys: no geometry column found

Comment: What is the data type of `geometryOfCellRepresentativeToTreatment`? It has to be a geometry

Comment: @JimJones it is a geometry

Comment: @JimJones, oh, i checked it in dbeaver, and it is text?!i will alter it

Comment: It must work, see this fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=dbe014a7baec15bbd6372ee674f2db63

Comment: @JimJones yes it works now. but i have to questions please.1-i would like to set initial value to geometry column, in python, when i set it to None or "", i get an error. then i set it to `0101000020E6100000000000000000F03F0000000000000040` and it worked. but this value is not the correct value to initialize a geometry.how the geometry column can be initialized please.2-do you know how to use the result of ST_AsMVTGeomandST_AsMVT in openlayers?

Comment: you mean you want to put a default value in your column, so that every time that a record is inserted and the geom column does not contain any value it becomes `0101000020E6100000000000000000F03F0000000000000040` ?

Comment: @JimJones yes, in other words, a value similar to null when the column contain no values"empty"

Comment: normally you should post another question for this, but I'll grant you this one ;) https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=70e801989db9d4de2b0fa99e53f09f74

Comment: @JimJones i will post a question for it, and explain it more clearer.but i ment, to set a default value to geom indicates that it is null or empty.for example, when a string initially is initialized to null or "" to indicate being void/empty. what is the equivalent to null/empty for geometries. is it clear

Comment: it is here:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69940446/what-is-the-suitable-value-to-initialize-an-empty-column-of-type-geometry

Comment: This other answer of mine (a bit old) on ST_AsMVT might interest you as well: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60016291/2275388

Answer (score 0):

It is an aggregate function like `count` or `sum`, and the first argument must be a composite type. (I wonder why PostGIS didn't declare the parameter as `record`.)

So you are expected call it like this, using a “whole-row reference”:

```
SELECT ST_AsMVT(grid_cell_data)
FROM grid_cell_data
[WHERE ...]
[GROUP BY ...]
```

Answer (score 0):

The function `ST_AsMVT` expects a row containing a geometry, not simply a geometry. One option to use it is to select the records in a `CTE` or `subquery`, so that you can chose which columns of your table are going to be used, e.g. `name` and `geometryOfCellRepresentativeToTreatment`:

```
SELECT ST_AsMVT(g) FROM (
  SELECT name,geometryOfCellRepresentativeToTreatment
  FROM grid_cell_data) g;
```

Or if you wish to use the whole record:

```
SELECT ST_AsMVT(grid_cell_data) 
FROM grid_cell_data
```

Regarding `ST_AsMVTGeom` you must provide at least a geometry and a the geometric bounds of the tile contents to make it work:

```
SELECT
 ST_AsText(
   ST_AsMVTGeom(
     geometryOfCellRepresentativeToTreatment,
     -- change to the envelope that suits your data set
     ST_MakeBox2D(ST_Point(0, 0), ST_Point(4096, 4096)))) 
FROM grid_cell_data;
```

Or combining both functions (see [documentation](https://postgis.net/docs/manual-dev/ST_AsMVT.html)):

```
WITH j AS (
 SELECT
   ST_AsMVTGeom(
     geometryOfCellRepresentativeToTreatment,
     ST_MakeBox2D(ST_Point(0, 0), ST_Point(4096, 4096)))
 FROM grid_cell_data
)
SELECT ST_AsMVT(j.*) FROM j;
```

Demo: [`db<>fiddle`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=e713d1cfd35798bee8dbbfc0e3514ab9)

Comment: would you please have a look at this question:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69944107/st-asmvtgeom-returns-empty-column

Comment: hi,would you please have a look at this question:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69984790/how-to-solve-parse-error-invalid-geometry

Comment: i got it thaks...i will delete the question

Comment: hi, would you please have a look at this question:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70017681/how-to-convert-cte-to-nested-select