# how to convert CTE to nested SELECT

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis, common-table-expression

i have the below posted query. i would like to use nested `SELECT` statement instead of `CTE`. i would like to have the outer `SELECT` statement stating the columns that are contained in the table `grid_cell_data`
i do not want to use `j.*` i want to use the columns names instead

**query**:

```
WITH j AS (
 SELECT
   ST_AsMVTGeom(
     st_geomfromtext(geometryofcellrepresentativetobuffer),
     ST_MakeBox2D(ST_Point(0, 0), ST_Point(4096,4096)))
 FROM grid_cell_data where id = 3
)
SELECT ST_AsMVT(j.*) FROM j
```

**grid_cell_data table**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS grid_cell_data (
   id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
   isTreatment boolean,
   isBuffer boolean,
   geometryOfCellRepresentativeToTreatment geometry,
   geometryOfCellRepresentativeToBuffer geometry 
)
```

Comment: and what is the question? Why can't you move your CTE to subselect ? Just copy `j AS (....)` from CTE to the FROM part like `(...) as  j`  in place of `j`. Seems straight forward.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to select all records you need in the CTE/Subquery and in the outer query you can keep using `j` or `j.*`. In case you need to further select specific columns, place them between parenthesis in the `SELECT`, so that it represents a record for `ST_AsMVT`, e.g.

```
WITH j AS (
 SELECT *,
   ST_AsMVTGeom(
     st_geomfromtext(geometryofcellrepresentativetobuffer),
     ST_MakeBox2D(ST_Point(0, 0), ST_Point(4096,4096))) AS mvt_geom
 FROM grid_cell_data where id = 3
)
SELECT ST_AsMVT((id,isTreatment,isBuffer,mvt_geom)) 
FROM j
```

Comment: would you please tell me why do we need (( and )) for st_asmvt?i know that it take a row not separate argument..is it how postgresql converts arguments to row?

Comment: is it possible to replace the first * with columns of my interest as well?

Comment: @LetsamrIt first question: columns separated by comma between parenthesis means a `record`, which is what the function expects. second question: yes, it is possible. you can do it in both ways

Comment: you mean between double parenthesis like (( )) not between single one, ia m i right?

Comment: @LetsamrIt the inner parenthesis belong to the record and the outer ones to the function itself

Comment: may i add another solution to the soultion you posted?

Comment: i do not know if this question for you or it is out of your expertise:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70106991/how-to-set-constraint-and-foreign-key-on-a-column