# how to set constraint and foreign key on a column

Tags: sql, postgresql

i have the below posted tables. i would like to specify a constraint and foreign key on the column called `fk_grid_cell` in `gridCellParticularPK` table.
below is my attempts, but when i execute it, it gives a syntay error

the error i am receiving is:

```
 syntax error at `constraint`
```

**tables**:

```
create table if not exists grid_cell(
           fourCornersTreatmentAsGeoJSON text,
           fourCornersBufferAsGeoJSON text,
           primary key (fourCornersTreatmentAsGeoJSON,fourCornersBufferAsGeoJSON)
    )
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS grid_cell_particular (
           gridCellParticularPK serial primary key,
           isTreatment boolean,
           isBuffer boolean,
           distanceFromTreatmentToNearestEdge float8,
           distanceFromBufferToNearestEdge float8,
    
           fk_grid_cell 
           constraint constrains_FK_gridCell_gridCellParticular 
           unique foreign key references grid_cell(fourCornersTreatmentAsGeoJSON,fourCornersBufferAsGeoJSON) 
           )
```

Comment: What is the error you get? The immediate problem seems to be a missing `;` after each statement.

Comment: @LetsamrIt to which columns in the table `grid_cell_particular` you want to map the foreign keys `fourCornersOfKeyWindowRepresentativeToTreatmentAsGeoJSON` and `fourCornersOfKeyWindowRepresentativeToBufferAsGeoJSON`?

Comment: @LetsamrIt and also, where are the columns for the primary key on `grid_cell`?

Comment: The two columns in table grid_cell you want to refer to in the foreign key are of type `text` whereas there is no column of type text in the table grid_cell_particular. You need to add two columns of type text if you want them to refer to the 2 columns in table grid_cell.

Comment: @JimJones yes. the pk of grid_cell is a composite one as shown in the code

Comment: @LetsamrIt you mean this? https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=0fcb6c41e6193e412ba425548c32f774

Comment: @JimJones but what is jsonb please

Comment: @LetsamrIt it is a data type designed to store json literals https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/datatype-json.html

Comment: @JimJones yes, it is working now thanks

Comment: @JimJones yes sure

Answer (score 0):

There are few things missing:

- The columns you're using for the primary key on `grid_cell` do not exist in the table: `fourCornersOfKeyWindowRepresentativeToTreatmentAsGeoJSON` and `fourCornersOfKeyWindowRepresentativeToBufferAsGeoJSON`.
- The column names on `grid_cell` suggest you're storing json strings, so you should be using the data type `jsonb` instead of `text`.
- The foreign key columns declared on the constraint on `grid_cell_particular` also do not exist on the table itself. In order to create a foreign key you must map the foreign columns to existing columns on your table. You can name them as you want, e.g. `fk_grid_cell_treatment` and `fk_grid_cell_buffer`.

Unrelated:

Consider using INDENTITY columns instead of `serial`. Check this out: [`Don't use serial`](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_serial)

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS grid_cell(
  fourCornersTreatmentAsGeoJSON jsonb,
  fourCornersBufferAsGeoJSON jsonb,
  fourCornersOfKeyWindowRepresentativeToTreatmentAsGeoJSON jsonb,
  fourCornersOfKeyWindowRepresentativeToBufferAsGeoJSON jsonb,
  PRIMARY KEY (fourCornersOfKeyWindowRepresentativeToTreatmentAsGeoJSON,
               fourCornersOfKeyWindowRepresentativeToBufferAsGeoJSON)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS grid_cell_particular (
  gridCellParticularPK serial PRIMARY KEY,
  isTreatment boolean,
  isBuffer boolean,
  distanceFromTreatmentToNearestEdge float8,
  distanceFromBufferToNearestEdge float8,    
  fk_grid_cell_treatment jsonb,
  fk_grid_cell_buffer jsonb,
  CONSTRAINT constrains_FK_gridCell_gridCellParticular 
    FOREIGN KEY (fk_grid_cell_treatment,fk_grid_cell_buffer)
      REFERENCES grid_cell 
       (fourCornersOfKeyWindowRepresentativeToTreatmentAsGeoJSON,
        fourCornersOfKeyWindowRepresentativeToBufferAsGeoJSON),
  CONSTRAINT unique_fk 
    UNIQUE (fk_grid_cell_treatment,fk_grid_cell_buffer)
 );
```

Comment: would you please tell show me where to add `unique` key word on the foreign key in the code you posted...because it is one to one relation

Comment: would you please have a look at this one please:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70107711/how-to-make-row-unique-in-one-to-many-relation